# Using bitwise operator instead unsupported boolean operator '-' for image masking with binary array

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing, bitwise-operators, mask

**Both systems' python version: 3.10.5**

I am trying to use a binary mask on my image and make a new binary image. What made me wonder was that while I was practicing this same thing on my other system with this same code, the output was generated but on another system, it is throwing this error back and the binary image isn't being generated. (Then I wanted to impose the under 40 valued pixel-based mask on the main image). The five-liner wee code is-

Here, I am trying to take the pixels whose values are under 40.

```
im = imread('image')
mask = im<40
plt.figure()
imshow(mask)
plt.show()
```

Error

```
      4 plt.figure()
----> 5 imshow(mask)
      6 plt.show()
      7

TypeError: numpy boolean subtract, the `-` operator, is not supported, use the bitwise_xor, the `^` operator, or the logical_xor function instead.

<Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>
```

*(Edit the query if needed, accordingly.)*

Comment: What is `imshow`? You need to include import statements so we know what you're doing and what functions you are calling. Please read [mre], then [edit] your post accordingly.

Comment: matplotlib doesn't like arrays of type bool, so convert it to some numeric type.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, I did not post the code to reproduce any errors from any member's end. Hence, I didn't attach the imshow's variable.

Comment: I don’t know what that means. But you need to read [mre], then [edit] your post accordingly. We don’t know if you are using pyplot’s `imshow` or OpenCV’s `imshow` or any other one. Also don’t know what `imread` you use, or what type is returned by it. Also, is it a color image or a grayscale image?

Answer (score -1):

you need to use numpy ma masked_where method:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
im = plt.imread('image')
mask = np.ma.masked_where(im < 40, im)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(mask)
plt.show()
```